# this.client.defaultMutationOptions is not a function react-query, pocketbase, nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-query

I'm trying to follow a series on using Pocketbase with NextJS, but I'm following a video which uses create-react-app, so I'm needing to make some changes along the way. It's been fun, but I'm stuck on this bit, and google gave no joy. It doesn't seem to be nextjs specific, but this is the first time I've seen mutations, so I don't really know. Here is the code:

```
"use client";
import pb from "@/lib/pocketbase";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useMutation } from "react-query";

export default function useLogin() {
  async function login({ email, password }) {
    const authData = await pb
      .collection("users")
      .authWithPassword(email, password);
  }

  return useMutation(login);
}
```

and the error is

```
TypeError: this.client.defaultMutationOptions is not a function
```

Everything was working fine until I tried to introduce the useMutation bit. For reference, the video is at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kBI_Bp06DpE&list=PLqFvlDFoiZ-0ixIS8D4JTHRuVy_rkfROY&index=4

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use new react-query v5 syntax with **mutationFn** key:

```
useMutation({
    mutationFn: login,
    onSuccess: () => {
      // Success actions
    },
    onError: (error) => {
      // Error actions
    },
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

wrong package "react-query" it should be "@tanstack/react-query"

import {useMutation} from "@tanstack/react-query"

aslo resintall react-query

npm install @tanstack/react-query